# Can't make a on click button to open an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error

I can't execute this code in console, I want to make a `onclick` button to open an `iframe` but when I paste it on console, it says "`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'`", any help? thanks!

```
document.getElementsByClassName("search-bar hp")[0].innerHTML = ("<button class=\'btn btn-primary btn-sm\' onclick=\'AbsenKuy()\'style=\'background-color:#000000;color:white;\'><span class=\'fa fa-bug\'> Auto Absensi</span></button>";

function AbsenKuy() {

document.getElementsByClassName("post-topbar")[0].innerHTML = "<iframe width=\'150 height=\'100\' src='http://elearning-man2kotabogor.sch.id/studentkelas/absensi/MTEyNUtaWQ==/U0VOQlVEX1hJX0tJTUlBX0FZRQ==/MTEyNQ=='></iframe>";
};

document.getElementsByClassName("search-bar hp")[0].innerHTML = ("<button class=\'btn btn-primary btn-sm\' onclick=\'AbsenKuy()\'style=\'background-color:#000000;color:white;\'><span class=\'fa fa-bug\'> Auto Absensi</span></button>";
function AbsenKuy() {
document.getElementsByClassName("post-topbar")[0].innerHTML = "<iframe width=\'150 height=\'100\' src='http://elearning-man2kotabogor.sch.id/studentkelas/absensi/MTEyNUtaWQ==/U0VOQlVEX1hJX0tJTUlBX0FZRQ==/MTEyNQ=='></iframe>";
};
```

Comment: Try to remove the ( after .innerHtml = on the first line

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have missed some closing brackets in the `script`.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("search-bar hp")[0] = ("<button class=\'btn btn-primary btn-sm\' onclick=\'AbsenKuy()\'style=\'background-color:#000000;color:white;\'><span class=\'fa fa-bug\'> Auto Absensi</span></button>");

function AbsenKuy() {

document.getElementsByClassName("post-topbar")[0].innerHTML = "<iframe width=\'150 height=\'100\' src='http://elearning-man2kotabogor.sch.id/studentkelas/absensi/MTEyNUtaWQ==/U0VOQlVEX1hJX0tJTUlBX0FZRQ==/MTEyNQ=='></iframe>"
};

document.getElementsByClassName("search-bar hp")[0] = ("<button class=\'btn btn-primary btn-sm\' onclick=\'AbsenKuy()\'style=\'background-color:#000000;color:white;\'><span class=\'fa fa-bug\'> Auto Absensi</span></button>");

function AbsenKuy() {
document.getElementsByClassName("post-topbar")[0].innerHTML = "<iframe width=\'150 height=\'100\' src='http://elearning-man2kotabogor.sch.id/studentkelas/absensi/MTEyNUtaWQ==/U0VOQlVEX1hJX0tJTUlBX0FZRQ==/MTEyNQ=='></iframe>"
};
```

This modified code will prevent that error. All the best.